# Show SAP CAP one to one association on Fiori Elements header on an object page

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-cap

Is there a way to show properties of a one to one navigation in Fiori Elements header?
Code I try to use:

```
entity SomeEntity : managed, cuid {
    name        : String(100);
    calculatedDetails : Association to one Detail on calculatedDetails.someEntity_ID = ID @readonly;
};

@readonly
entity Detail as select from SomeTable {
    someEntity_ID,
    avg(calc) as propertyToShow
} where ( calc > 0) group by someEntity_ID order by someEntity_ID;
```

with following idea of an annotation on the `SomeEntity`

```
    HeaderFacets       : [
    {
        $Type : 'UI.ReferenceFacet',
        Label : '{i18n>DETAIL}',
        Target : 'calculatedDetails/@UI.FieldGroup'
    }
    ],
```

And on the Detail entity I defined a `FieldGroup` like this

```
    FieldGroup: {Data: [
        {
            Value: calculatedDetails 
        }
    ]},
```